# change the width and height of textfield in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, textfield

I have a Flash file, which has to be liquid. I have a header, a footer and a center section, which all are percentage scalable. My center section has a MovieClip called info_txt, and I'm trying to make it high 20% of the center_mc's height. I do this, but I also load a text in that field (info_txt) with XML, and when the text (xml) is loaded and placed in the textfield it doesn't go multiline, but stays nowrap. How to fix this please tell me!

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
your_textfield.autoSize = "left";
your_textfield.wordWrap = true;
```

In case you need more info: [Adobe help on AutoSize property (TextField.autoSize) for AS2](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001583.html)

Comment: that didn't work, but I decided to create and position the textfields dinamically with `createTextField()` and after that format them to work for my needs (so center_mc no longer exists). If there's only one textfield everything is fine, but when I make a second or third it goes too heavy.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED! It was heavy, because of the onEnterFrame loop and XML. Removed the onEnterFrame and loaded the text from .txt files :)